# call .htc file from all html pages withot adding url domain

Tags: html-components

In that same CSS rule, add the following style line:

```
behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);
```

Of course you will need to adjust the path to match where you uploaded PIE.htc in step 2. Note: this path is relative to the HTML file being viewed, not the CSS file it is called from.

but if my url is domain.com/foo/foo.html PIE.htc is not loaded any more if i use

```
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

PIE.htc is located in root. Can i somehow always call .htc file from root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URIs starting with a `/` are relative to the site root.

Comment: Starting with a `/` should work. You probably are miscalculating the actual path to the file.

Comment: The "root of the web page" is `<html>`, which is meaningless. In a URL `/` means the root of the website, and you can construct the rest of your URL from there. It is **not** home page specific.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior property requires the URI to the HTC file to be specified using the URL() syntax. Multiple HTC files can be referenced with a space-delimited list.

So suppose your **csshover.htc** file is in **csshover** directory and you can reference multiple HTC file or specially same file but from different directories 
like `behavior: URL('csshover/csshover.htc') URL('../csshover/csshover.htc') URL('../../csshover/csshover.htc') URL('../../../csshover/csshover.htc');` and so on.